# Is Ripple's distributed exchange scalable?

Tags: exchanges, ripple, scalability

[This question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8976/is-ripple-com-scalable) asks about the scalability of Ripple in general, and has an ok answer.

However, it doesn't mention the [distributed exchange built in Ripple](https://ripple.com/wiki/Distributed_Exchange). How is its current/future architecture designed to cope with scale?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. As long as Ripple itself works, do you have any reason to believe this subset of its feature could stop working on its own?

Comment: @Lohoris - I envision a possibility that other parts of Ripple are scalable (like Bitcoin, as the answer says), which the distributed exchange might not be. I have no idea whether this possibility is real or not, I would simply like some input from someone who understands the order matching engine, and can comment whether it, too, is "as scalable as Bitcoin".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is designed to be highly scalable.

Offers are aggregated with others offers of the same currency pair in the same direction of the same quality (rate). The ledger has a "next index" operation and offers are indexed by quality, so finding the best offer in an order book is as simple as computing the index for the base of the order book and looking at the next ledger entry.